# Issue with passing an int field in as a parameter argument, but all others work perfectlyy how is this even possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[ScreenShot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RE5D.png)Could someone please explain to me how everything works in this script except a simple int counter that I pass in as a parameter? However if I directly pass in the int counter field into the method instead of using/ref. the para, it works just fine, how is this even possible? HELP!

Comment: Can you edit the code into the question instead of a screen shot and try describing what the behavior you're seeing is and what the desired behavior would be. Since you have not described what the code is supposed to do how would anyone know what you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

By default parameters you give to the function, are evaluated and its value is passed (eg. not `int xy` is passed but the value of `int xy`, so `5`).

So if you change the value directly eg. `CounterAi -= 1;` you are just changing the value you've passed on not the underlying variable. So if you want to use **Pass by Reference** in these cases you must use `out` or `ref`.

---

If you change a parameter of the passed value however it's value will be changed without needing to use `ref` or `out`.

**Example:**

```cs
public void Example1(int myValue) {
    // This won't change the actual variable, just the value of the parameter,
    // that has been passed
    myValue -= 1;
}

public void Example2(ref int myValue) {
    // This will change the actual variable,
    // it's changing just the value of the parameter again, 
    // but we're using pass by reference
    myValue -= 1;
}

public void Example3(Transform finishLine) {
    // This will change the actual variable,
    // because it's changing the data within the object,
    // that the parameter value refers to.
    finishLine.position = flSpts[Random.Range(0, flSpots.Count)].position;
}
```